# filtering on Class name not working using jquery filter method

Tags: jquery

When I attempt to filter on a class name using jquery filter method, it does not work (no data is inserted into the #Test1Section', 
for example,

```
     $(data).find('.test1WrapperDiv').appendTo('#Test1Section');
```

but if when I use the element name as a filter it works but not what I won't.

```
    $(data).find('div').appendTo('#Test1Section');
```

php file

```
         echo "<div class='test1WrapperDiv'>";
                echo "<div><p> Row 1 </p></div>";
                echo "<div><p> Row 2 </p></div>";
                echo "<div><p> Row 3 </p></div>";
                echo "<div><p> Row 4 </p></div>";
          echo "</div>";

          echo "<div class='test2WrapperDiv'>";
                echo "<div><p> Row 1 </p></div>";
                echo "<div><p> Row 2 </p></div>";
                echo "<div><p> Row 3 </p></div>";
                echo "<div><p> Row 4 </p></div>";
          echo "</div>";


          $.post("test.php",{sendword: test1, table: table_name1}
          function(data)
          {
              $(data).find('.test1WrapperDiv').appendTo('#Test1Section');
          });
```

How do I get it to work using a CSS class name?

Answer (score 1):

The `find()` method finds **children** of the given selection. You have few ways to go about it

1. fix your HTML returned to have single root element (add another div around it)
2. replace `find()` call with `filter()`
3. change selection context `$('.test1WrapperDiv', data).appendTo('#Test1Section');`